# Contour from a list of {lat,long,values}

Tags: python, mesh, contour, netcdf4

I need to create a contour using python. The problem is that all the solutions I have found so far are mesh based which require 3 arrays:
lats array
long array
values array
then they use mesh to make the contour.
The problem in my case is that every single value has a different lat and long and it's more like the following array
[{lat,long,values},{lat,long,values},{lat,long,values},{lat,long,values}]

I appreciate any solution or recommendation

the original values are like this. 3 2D arrays

Values :

```
[[[2.3000e-01 2.2250e-01 2.3500e-01 ... 5.0000e-03 1.2500e-02 1.2500e-02]
  [2.3250e-01 2.2500e-01 2.3000e-01 ... 7.5000e-03 1.2500e-02 1.2500e-02]
  [2.4500e-01 2.3000e-01 2.2250e-01 ... 7.5000e-03 1.2500e-02 1.2500e-02]
  ...
  [1.1979e+02 1.1979e+02 1.1979e+02 ... 6.9500e-01 7.0000e-01 7.0500e-01]
  [1.1979e+02 1.1979e+02 1.1979e+02 ... 6.9500e-01 7.0000e-01 7.0500e-01]
  [1.1979e+02 1.1979e+02 1.1979e+02 ... 6.9500e-01 7.0000e-01 7.0500e-01]]]
```

Lats:

```
[[18.14503    18.17840149 18.21173404 ... 20.95232678 20.92303157
  20.89368282]
 [18.19869826 18.23212537 18.26551351 ... 21.01085369 20.98150583
  20.95210438]
 [18.25238237 18.28586518 18.31930902 ... 21.06940562 21.04000501
  21.01055075]
 ...
 [47.37108253 47.45317877 47.53531405 ... 54.84178113 54.75671371
  54.67167336]
 [47.35484472 47.43689746 47.51898908 ... 54.82084335 54.73583959
  54.65086259]
 [47.33843536 47.42044418 47.5024917  ... 54.79968906 54.71474955
  54.62983649]]
```

longs:

```
[[217.107456   217.16395904 217.22053137 ... 275.5738218  275.63644491
  275.69899943]
 [217.07228304 217.12882027 217.18542696 ... 275.60519679 275.66787119
  275.73047681]
 [217.03704065 217.09361204 217.15025307 ... 275.63664054 275.69936627
  275.762023  ]
 ...
 [147.8669735  147.84307356 147.81907208 ... 352.75647981 352.72040049
  352.68450633]
 [147.74583254 147.72168602 147.697437   ... 352.90413813 352.86770214
  352.8314529 ]
 [147.62479343 147.60040096 147.57590506 ... 353.05160828 353.01481704
  352.97821413]]
```

I extracted this values from a netcdf file

Comment: Please add some example input and expected output.

Comment: I would look into interpolating your points onto a regular 2D grid, for example using [`scipy.interpolate.griddata`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html)

Comment: @xnx Thanks for your response. I thought about interpolation. but I don't want to scrifice the accuracy of values as far as it is possible. Do you know any other solution?

Comment: @sun1987 a contour joins latitude and longitude points with the same value. So unless your data contains the coordinates of points with contour values points you want to indicate, I don't see how you can do what you want without interpolation of some kind.

Comment: Thans right. thank you @xnx